# Limits send messages using twilio whatsapp API

Tags: twilio

I want to know what are the limits in Twilio to send mass messages using the WhatsApp API, I want to send notifications of the use of my site to 2,500 numbers but I don't know if that is going to be taken as spam and they will block my account.

Does anyone know if twilio allows me to do this? or what can I do to be able to send notifications to 2,500 numbers without being blocked.

regards!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't limit the number of messages you can send, but WhatsApp does while you ramp up your application.

[From the docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024008153-WhatsApp-Rate-Limiting):

> Every new WhatsApp-enabled number is initialized at Tier 1. WhatsApp monitors message volume as well as quality, and will automatically move customers between tiers based on the total number of unique recipients across the past 7 days.
>
> If within the past 7 days, a WhatsApp-enabled Twilio phone number has communicated with 2x the unique recipients of the per-day limit, and maintains a good "quality rating" from WhatsApp, that number will be automatically moved to the next tier on the next day.

The tiers are:

| Tier | Limit |
| --- | --- |
| Tier 1 | Limited to **1,000** unique message recipients per day |
| Tier 2 | Limited to **10,000** unique message recipients per day |
| Tier 3 | Limited to **100,000** unique message recipients per day |

You can read more about [the different tiers and how WhatsApp calculates a quality rating in the documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024008153-WhatsApp-Rate-Limiting).

Ultimately, you should be able to send 2,500 messages to your recipients, you just have to ramp up to that slowly.